# I wrote a test class for my Apex class, and all the asserts are successful, but it says "zero coverage"

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am new to Apex, so I built these classes mostly by doing copy-and-paste and so building my class based on an Apex class that someone else had previously written. They had also written a Test class, which I copied. The changes I made were moderate. If I run the Test class, all of the asserts are successful. And yet, when I try to deploy my code to production, I'm told that my Apex class has zero coverage.

I'm curious if the original classes, which I copied, are judged to have at least 75% coverage. How would I find out? Is there a way I can see what percent of an Apex class is considered covered, other than deploying it?

I've simplified this somewhat, but the Apex class looks like this:

```
public with sharing class ftg_Picker_Matcher {

@InvocableMethod(label='Picker Value Mapping' description='Accepts a Key and Map Name and returns the mapped value.' category='Utility')
public static List<Result> getPickerMappedValue(List<Request> reqs) {
    List<Result> allResults = new List<Result>();
    
    for ( Request req : reqs) {
        Result resultResponse = new Result();

        if (req.key == null) {
            resultResponse.mappedValue = null;
            resultResponse.errorDescription = 'Null Key Provided';
            System.debug('Null Key Provided');  
        } else {
            Map<String, String> tempMap = new Map<String, String>();          
            switch on req.sourceSystem {
                when 'Sugar' {  
                    switch on req.destSystem {    
                        when 'Blood_CP' {     
                            switch on req.PickerName {
                                when 'Country' {
                                    tempMap = new Map<String, String>{'Afghanistan' => 'Afghanistan','Aland Islands' => 'Aland Islands','Albania' => 'Albania','Algeria' => 'Algeria','American Samoa' => 'American Samoa','Andorra' => 'Andorra','Angola' => 'Angola','Anguilla' => 'Anguilla','Antarctica' => 'Antarctica','Antigua and Barbuda' => 'Antigua And Barbuda','Argentina' => 'Argentina','Armenia' => 'Armenia','Aruba' => 'Aruba','Australia' => 'Australia','Austria' => 'Austria','Azerbaijan' => 'Azerbaijan','Bahamas' => 'Bahamas','Bahrain' => 'Bahrain','Bangladesh' => 'Bangladesh','Barbados' => 'Barbados','Belarus' => 'Belarus','Belgium' => 'Belgium','Belize' => 'Belize','Benin' => 'Benin','Bermuda' => 'Bermuda','Bhutan' => 'Bhutan','Bolivia' => 'Bolivia','Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba' => 'Bonaire,Sint Eustatius and Saba','Bosnia and Herzegovina' => 'Bosnia and Herzegovina','Botswana' => 'Botswana','Bouvet Island' => 'Bouvet Island','Brazil' => 'Brazil','British Indian Ocean Territory' => 'British Indian Ocean Territory','Brunei Darussalam' => 'Brunei Darussalam','Bulgaria' => 'Bulgaria','Burkina Faso' => 'Burkina Faso','Burundi' => 'Burundi','Cambodia' => 'Cambodia','Cameroon' => 'Cameroon','Canada' => 'Canada','Cape Verde' => 'Cape Verde','Cayman Islands' => 'Cayman Islands','Central African Republic' => 'Central African Republic','Chad' => 'Chad','Chile' => 'Chile','China' => 'China','Christmas Island' => 'Christmas Island','Cocos (Keeling) Islands' => 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands','Colombia' => 'Colombia','Comoros' => 'Comoros','Congo' => 'Congo','Congo, Democratic Republic of the' => 'Congo','Cook Islands' => 'Cook Islands','Costa Rica' => 'Costa Rica','Côte d\'Ivoire' => 'Cote d\'Ivoire','Croatia' => 'Croatia','Cuba' => 'Cuba','Curaçao' => 'Curacao','Cyprus' => 'Cyprus','Czech Republic' => 'Czech Republic','Denmark' => 'Denmark','Djibouti' => 'Djibouti','Dominica' => 'Dominica','Dominican Republic' => 'Dominican Republic','Ecuador' => 'Ecuador','Egypt' => 'Egypt','El Salvador' => 'El Salvador','Equatorial Guinea' => 'Equatorial Guinea','Eritrea' => 'Eritrea','Estonia' => 'Estonia','Eswatini' => 'Swaziland','Ethiopia' => 'Ethiopia','Falkland Islands' => 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)','Faroe Islands' => 'Faroe Islands','Fiji' => 'Fiji','Finland' => 'Finland','France' => 'France','French Guiana' => 'French Guiana','French Polynesia' => 'French Polynesia','French Southern Territories' => 'French Southern Territories','Gabon' => 'Gabon','Gambia' => 'Gambia','Georgia' => 'Georgia','Germany' => 'Germany','Ghana' => 'Ghana','Gibraltar' => 'Gibraltar','Greece' => 'Greece','Greenland' => 'Greenland','Grenada' => 'Grenada','Guadeloupe' => 'Guadeloupe','Guam' => 'Guam','Guatemala' => 'Guatemala','Guernsey' => 'Guernsey','Guinea' => 'Guinea','Guinea-Bissau' => 'Guinea-Bissau','Guyana' => 'Guyana','Haiti' => 'Haiti','Heard Island and McDonald Islands' => 'Heard Island and McDonald Islands','Holy See (Vatican City State)' => 'Holy See (Vatican City State)','Honduras' => 'Honduras','Hong Kong' => 'Hong Kong','Hungary' => 'Hungary','Iceland' => 'Iceland','India' => 'India','Indonesia' => 'Indonesia','Iran' => 'Iraq','Iraq' => 'Iraq','Ireland' => 'Ireland','Isle of Man' => 'Isle of Man','Israel' => 'Israel','Italy' => 'Italy','Ivory Coast' => 'Cote d\'Ivoire','Jamaica' => 'Jamaica','Japan' => 'Japan','Jersey' => 'Jersey','Jordan' => 'Jordan','Kazakhstan' => 'Kazakhstan','Kenya' => 'Kenya','Kiribati' => 'Kiribati','Korea, Democratic People\'s Republic of' => 'Korea','Korea, Republic of' => 'Korea','Kuwait' => 'Kuwait','Kyrgyzstan' => 'Kyrgyzstan','Lao People\'s Democratic Republic' => 'Lao People\'s Democratic Republic','Latvia' => 'Latvia','Lebanon' => 'Lebanon','Lesotho' => 'Lesotho','Liberia' => 'Liberia','Libya' => 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya','Liechtenstein' => 'Liechtenstein','Lithuania' => 'Lithuania','Luxembourg' => 'Luxembourg','Macao' => 'MACAO','Madagascar' => 'Madagascar','Malawi' => 'Malawi','Malaysia' => 'Malaysia','Maldives' => 'Maldives','Mali' => 'Mali','Malta' => 'Malta','Marshall Islands' => 'Marshall Islands','Martinique' => 'Martinique','Mauritania' => 'Mauritania','Mauritius' => 'Mauritius','Mayotte' => 'Mayotte','Mexico' => 'Mexico','Micronesia' => 'Micronesia, Federated States of','Moldova' => 'Moldova, Republic of','Monaco' => 'Monaco','Mongolia' => 'Mongolia','Montenegro' => 'Montenegro','Montserrat' => 'Montserrat','Morocco' => 'Morocco','Mozambique' => 'Mozambique','Myanmar' => 'Myanmar','Namibia' => 'Namibia','Nauru' => 'Nauru','Nepal' => 'Nepal','Netherlands' => 'Netherlands','New Caledonia' => 'New Caledonia','New Zealand' => 'New Zealand','Nicaragua' => 'Nicaragua','Niger' => 'Niger','Nigeria' => 'Nigeria','Niue' => 'Niue','Norfolk Island' => 'Norfolk Island','Northern Mariana Islands' => 'Northern Mariana Islands','North MBlood_CPdonia' => 'MBlood_CPdonia, The former Yugoslav Republic Of','Norway' => 'Norway','Oman' => 'Oman','Pakistan' => 'Pakistan','Palau' => 'Palau','Palestine' => 'Palestinian Territory, Occupied','Panama' => 'Panama','Papua New Guinea' => 'Papua New Guinea','Paraguay' => 'Paraguay','Peru' => 'Peru','Philippines' => 'Philippines','Pitcairn' => 'Pitcairn','Poland' => 'Poland','Portugal' => 'Portugal','Puerto Rico' => 'Puerto Rico','Qatar' => 'Qatar','Réunion' => 'Reunion','Romania' => 'Romania','Russian Federation' => 'Russia','Rwanda' => 'Rwanda','Saint Barthélemy' => 'Saint Barthelemy','Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha' => 'Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan Da Cunha','Saint Kitts and Nevis' => 'Saint Kitts and Nevis','Saint Lucia' => 'Saint Lucia','Saint Martin (French part)' => 'Saint Martin (French Part )','Saint Pierre and Miquelon' => 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon','Saint Vincent and the Grenadines' => 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines','Samoa' => 'Samoa','San Marino' => 'San Marino','Sao Tome and Principe' => 'Sao Tome and Principe','Saudi Arabia' => 'Saudi Arabia','Senegal' => 'Senegal','Serbia' => 'Serbia','Seychelles' => 'Seychelles','Sierra Leone' => 'Sierra Leone','Singapore' => 'Singapore','Sint Maarten (Dutch part)' => 'Sint Maarten (Dutch Part)','Slovakia' => 'Slovakia','Slovenia' => 'Slovenia','Solomon Islands' => 'Solomon Islands','Somalia' => 'Somalia','South Africa' => 'South Africa','South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands' => 'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands','South Sudan' => 'South Sudan','Spain' => 'Spain','Sri Lanka' => 'Sri Lanka','Sudan' => 'Sudan','Suriname' => 'Suriname','Svalbard and Jan Mayen' => 'Svalbard and Jan Mayen','Sweden' => 'Sweden','Switzerland' => 'Switzerland','Syrian Arab Republic' => 'Syrian Arab Republic','Taiwan' => 'Taiwan','Tajikistan' => 'Tajikistan','Tanzania' => 'Tanzania','Thailand' => 'Thailand','Timor-Leste' => 'Timor-Leste','Togo' => 'Togo','Tokelau' => 'Tokelau','Tonga' => 'Tonga','Trinidad and Tobago' => 'Trinidad and Tobago','Tunisia' => 'Tunisia','Turkey' => 'Turkey','Turkmenistan' => 'Turkmenistan','Turks and Caicos Islands' => 'Turks and Caicos Islands','Tuvalu' => 'Tuvalu','Uganda' => 'Uganda','Ukraine' => 'Ukraine','United Arab Emirates' => 'United Arab Emirates','United Kingdom' => 'United Kingdom','United States' => 'United States','United States Minor Outlying Islands' => 'United States Minor Outlying Islands','Uruguay' => 'Uruguay','Uzbekistan' => 'Uzbekistan','Vanuatu' => 'Vanuatu','Venezuela' => 'Venezuela','Vietnam' => 'Viet Nam','Virgin Islands, British' => 'VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH','Virgin Islands (U.S.)' => 'VIRGIN ISLANDS, U.S.','Wallis and Futuna' => 'Wallis and Futuna','Western Sahara' => 'Western Sahara','Yemen' => 'Yemen','Zambia' => 'Zambia','Zimbabwe' => 'Zimbabwe'};
                                }
                                when else {
                                    resultResponse.mappedValue = null;
                                    resultResponse.errorDescription = 'Unknown Picker';

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        when else {
                            resultResponse.mappedValue = null;
                            resultResponse.errorDescription = 'Unknown Destination System for Source: ' + req.sourceSystem;
                        }
                    }
                }
                when else {
                    resultResponse.mappedValue = null;
                    resultResponse.errorDescription = 'Unknown Source System';
                }
            }
            
            if (resultResponse.errorDescription == null) { // It'll be populated if there was an error already.
                resultResponse.mappedValue = tempMap.get(req.key) ;
                if (resultResponse.mappedValue == null) { resultResponse.errorDescription = 'No value found for supplied Key: ' + req.key +'.';}
            }
            System.debug('Error: ' + resultResponse.errorDescription);
        }
        allResults.add(resultResponse);
    }

    return allResults;
}

public class Request {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Key' description='The key to lookup in the map' required=false)
    public String key;

    @InvocableVariable(label='Source System' description='Value is Sugar or Blood_CP' required=true)
    public String sourceSystem;

    @InvocableVariable(label='Destination System' description='Value is Blood_CP or Fiesta' required=true)
    public String destSystem;

    @InvocableVariable(label='The Picker to use' description='This will determine which map to lookup' required=true)
    public String PickerName;
}

public class Result {
    @InvocableVariable(label='The value associated with provided key.' required=false)
    public String mappedValue;

    @InvocableVariable(label='Only populated if there is an error' required=false)
    public String errorDescription;
}
}
```

The test looks like this:

```
@istest
public with sharing class ftg_Picker_Matcher_Test {
@istest
static void BadValues() {

    req = new ftg_Picker_Matcher.Request();
    req.key = 'keyA';
    req.sourceSystem = 'Not A Source';
    req.PickerName = 'Not a Picker';
    reqList.add(req);
    resultList = ftg_Picker_Matcher.getPickerMappedValue(reqList);

    system.assertEquals('Unknown Source System', resultList[0].errorDescription);
    reqList.clear();

    req = new ftg_Picker_Matcher.Request();
    req.key = null;
    req.sourceSystem = 'Not A Source';
    req.PickerName = 'Not a Picker';
    reqList.add(req);
    resultList = ftg_Picker_Matcher.getPickerMappedValue(reqList);

    system.assertEquals('Null Key Provided', resultList[0].errorDescription);
    reqList.clear();

    req = new ftg_Picker_Matcher.Request();
    req.key = 'keyA';
    req.sourceSystem = 'Blood_CP';
    req.destSystem = 'Fiesta';
    req.PickerName = 'Not a Picker';
    reqList.add(req);
    resultList = ftg_Picker_Matcher.getPickerMappedValue(reqList);

    system.assertEquals('Unknown Destination System for Source: ' + req.sourceSystem, resultList[0].errorDescription);
    reqList.clear();
}

@istest
static void GoodValues() {

    req = new ftg_Picker_Matcher.Request();
    req.key = 'Aland Islands';
    req.sourceSystem = 'Sugar';
    req.destSystem = 'Blood_CP';
    req.PickerName = 'Country';
    reqList.add(req);
    resultList = ftg_Picker_Matcher.getPickerMappedValue(reqList);

    system.assertEquals('Aland Islands', resultList[0].mappedValue);
    reqList.clear();

    req = new ftg_Picker_Matcher.Request();
    req.key = 'Aland Islands';
    req.sourceSystem = 'Blood_CP';
    req.destSystem = 'Sugar';
    req.PickerName = 'Country';
    reqList.add(req);
    resultList = ftg_Picker_Matcher.getPickerMappedValue(reqList);

    system.assertEquals('Aland Islands', resultList[0].mappedValue);
    reqList.clear();

}
}
```

I admit that I'm confused by the use of the Request and Result classes.

The question is this: what do I need to do to get at least 75% coverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if something was lost in translation, but your unit test had to be fixed up for some undeclared variables.

```
@istest
public with sharing class ftg_Picker_Matcher_Test {
    @istest
    static void BadValues() {
        ftg_Picker_Matcher.Request[] reqList = new ftg_Picker_Matcher.Request[0];
        ftg_Picker_Matcher.Result[] resultList = new ftg_Picker_Matcher.Result[0];
        ftg_Picker_Matcher.Request req = new ftg_Picker_Matcher.Request();
        req.key = 'keyA';
        req.sourceSystem = 'Not A Source';
        req.PickerName = 'Not a Picker';
        reqList.add(req);
        resultList = ftg_Picker_Matcher.getPickerMappedValue(reqList);
        
        system.assertEquals('Unknown Source System', resultList[0].errorDescription);
        reqList.clear();
        
        req = new ftg_Picker_Matcher.Request();
        req.key = null;
        req.sourceSystem = 'Not A Source';
        req.PickerName = 'Not a Picker';
        reqList.add(req);
        resultList = ftg_Picker_Matcher.getPickerMappedValue(reqList);
        
        system.assertEquals('Null Key Provided', resultList[0].errorDescription);
        reqList.clear();
        
        req = new ftg_Picker_Matcher.Request();
        req.key = 'keyA';
        req.sourceSystem = 'Blood_CP';
        req.destSystem = 'Fiesta';
        req.PickerName = 'Not a Picker';
        reqList.add(req);
        resultList = ftg_Picker_Matcher.getPickerMappedValue(reqList);
        
        system.assertEquals('Unknown Destination System for Source: ' + req.sourceSystem, resultList[0].errorDescription);
        reqList.clear();
    }
    
    @istest
    static void GoodValues() {
        ftg_Picker_Matcher.Request[] reqList = new ftg_Picker_Matcher.Request[0];
        ftg_Picker_Matcher.Result[] resultList = new ftg_Picker_Matcher.Result[0];
        ftg_Picker_Matcher.Request req = new ftg_Picker_Matcher.Request();
        req.key = 'Aland Islands';
        req.sourceSystem = 'Sugar';
        req.destSystem = 'Blood_CP';
        req.PickerName = 'Country';
        reqList.add(req);
        resultList = ftg_Picker_Matcher.getPickerMappedValue(reqList);
        
        system.assertEquals('Aland Islands', resultList[0].mappedValue);
        reqList.clear();
        
        req = new ftg_Picker_Matcher.Request();
        req.key = 'Aland Islands';
        req.sourceSystem = 'Blood_CP';
        req.destSystem = 'Sugar';
        req.PickerName = 'Country';
        reqList.add(req);
        resultList = ftg_Picker_Matcher.getPickerMappedValue(reqList);
        
        system.assertEquals('Aland Islands', resultList[0].mappedValue);
        reqList.clear();
        
    }
}
```

When you go to deploy your code, make certain that you are deploying both the main and unit tests. If you do not deploy the unit test with the code, you'll get 0% coverage. According to my org, this code currently has 84% coverage if the test is run correctly.

Comment: Hmm, this is so weird. I deploy the Apex class and the Test class in the same change set. I'm assuming Salesforce knows how to automatically find the test, based on some naming convention? I did obfuscate a little for the sake of posting on Stackexchange, so that might be why some variables were missing. Can I reasonably assume that if there were undeclared variable in my actual code then I'd see the errors? Right now the asserts in the Test all pass successfully.

Comment: I am grateful for the help. Follow up question: I guess this is stupid on my part, but do I need to do something to activate the test class? I was assuming Salesforce would find it automatically. I deploy the Apex class and the the Test class at the same time.

Comment: Okay, I'm an idiot. I just needed to specify the test class and everything worked. Thank you much.

Comment: @charlottesville Hey, it's happened to probably literally every one of us, either because we didn't know or we overlooked the test class by accident. It's a learning experience either way. I'm glad you got it resolved.